# select with multiple condition MAX

Tags: sql

How to select data with multiple condition max

```
SELECT * FROM [TEMP_TBL]
WHERE "FLDR_NUM" =(SELECT MAX(FLDR_NUM)
                   FROM [TEMP_TBL]) AND "DNLD_DT" =(SELECT MAX(DNLD_DT)
                                                    FROM [TEMP_TBL)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `cte` to reuse your `max()` value.

```
with cte(maxflr) as (
    select max(fldr_num) as maxflr from TEMP_TBL
)select * from TEMP_TBL 
cross apply cte
where "FLDR_NUM" = cte.maxflr and "DNLD_DT" = cte.maxflr
```